# Perl capture between single quotes in a one-liner

Tags: perl

I am trying to print out the text that is surrounded by single quotes.

```
/bin/bash -lc '/home/CASPER_REPORTS/scripts/CASPER_gen_report.sh CASPER_1'
/bin/bash -lc '/home/CASPER_REPORTS/scripts/CASPER_gen_report.sh CASPER_1A'
/bin/bash -lc '/home/CASPER_REPORTS/scripts/CASPER_gen_report.sh CASPER_2'
/bin/bash -lc '/home/CASPER_REPORTS/scripts/CASPER_gen_report.sh CASPER_3'
/bin/bash -lc '/home/CASPER_REPORTS/scripts/CASPER_gen_report.sh CASPER_3A'
```

The Boolean one I guess means that perl sees the string.

```
$ cat /tmp/casper_reports | perl -nle 'print /'.*'/'
1
1
1
1
1
```

However when I try and capture it with the parenthesis it throws an error

```
$ cat /tmp/boobomb | perl -nle 'print /'(.*)'/'
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: `perl -nle "print /'(.*)'/"`

Comment: The syntax for escaping a `'` is insane, so if you can avoid it, ^

Comment: As an aside, lose the [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Bash and Zsh shells, you can use `$''` to allow escaped single quotes.

```
echo $'I wouldn\'t'
```

This also keeps `$1` from being interpreted by bash and available to perl too.

```
perl -nle $'print $1 if /\'(.*)\'/' < /tmp/boobomb
```

also see 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30903/how-to-escape-quotes-in-shell

Comment: This form of escaping does not work in `csh`, `dash`, or `sh`. May be worth noting that this is a `bash`/`zsh` -specific feature.

Answer (score 6):

Use hex for the single quote (27) via [hexadecimal escape](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Character-Escapes), so `\x27`

```
perl -wnE'say $1 if /\x27(.*)\x27/' input.txt
```

This assumes a single pair of single quotes, per shown sample data on which it was tested.